# Custom Converter for Iterable Query Param

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

Is it possible to create a custom converter for Iterable types with Retrofit?

```kotlin
@Get("someEndpoint")
fun getData(enums: @Query("enum") EnumSet<MyEnum>)
```

I want to pass the markets to the REST API as a comma separated list of values (that's the only format it accepts).

If I create a custom Converter, I am only provided access to each individual `MyEnum` inside of the EnumSet, and that generates a URI like `&enum=enum1&enum=enum2`. Unfortunately, the backend API does not accept this format.

```kotlin
private class EnumSetConverter : Converter.Factory() {
        override fun stringConverter(
            type: Type,
            annotations: Array<out Annotation>,
            retrofit: Retrofit,
        ): Converter<MyEnum, String>? = if (type == MyEnum::class.java) {
                Converter<MyEnum, String> { me ->
                    me.name.lowercase()
                }
            } else {
                null
            }
    }
```

Is there a way to provide a converter for the EnumSet as a whole?